# why "using std::xxx" works but "using namespace std" doesn't

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

namespace A
{
using namespace std;  // "using std::exp" works however

struct Foo {};
Foo exp(Foo f);
int a = exp(5);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << A::a;
    return 0;
}
```

I know that using the whole namespace std is a bad practice, and just wonder that why "using namespace std" cannot compile but "using std::exp" works.

In my understanding, "using std::exp" is a subset of "using namespace std", and std::exp are pulled to the global namespace in both cases.

Comment: I recommend reading this: https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2020/12/21/using-directive/

Comment: @chris StackOverflow posts are expected to be self-contained. Link-only answers (or, in this case, comment) are discouraged. If the link breaks in the future, the information is not accessible. So, it would be best for future readers if you would post an actual answer here. You can include *relevant* information from that link as needed. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)